# Did Joey get to live with Chandler and Monica?

Tags: friends

In one of the final episodes of the Friends TV series, there is a scene where Monica and Chandler take Joey to visit the new house they are buying. There is a conversation between them like this:

> Monica: Now that you're okay with the house, do you wanna go see your room?
>
> Joey: What? I get my own room?
>
> Chandler: You don't think we'd buy a house and not have a Joey room
>   do you?

It's like that they will be living in the same house. But there's another scene when Monica breaks down the foosball machine to rescue the chicken, Chandler asks Joey if he would buy a new one, and he says no, because there is no point in it when there's no one to play with.

So, were they going to live in the same house or not?

Comment: Guess we would just have to wait for the movie...the trailer also gives an idea.

Comment: @AachmanShukla That trailer is not an official movie trailer. I don't know the exact background, but there is no movie planned and Lisa Kudrow recently said she could never imagine a Friends movie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Joey room" isn't intended as a permanent residence for Joey. At his own surprised reaction you can already see that there was never a plan to have Joey living with them in their house. That would be a stetch even for Joey's and Chandler's relationship to have him living with Chandler and Monica in their house.

Rather than that, the room is likely intended as a guest room dedicated specifically for Joey whenever he visits them and stays at their house. Either that or a kind of "hobby room" for Chandler and Joey to hang out in whenever he visits.

The comment is rather tongue-in-cheek to begin with, so it's likely not a room *only* for Joey. It's a reminiscence to the good times Joey and Chandler had and a reassurance for him that those times, while maybe getting fewer, won't stop just because he got his own house to live in with Monica, a reminder that there will *always* be someone to play foosball with.

Comment: I'd like to see a show about three of them live in Chandler's house and Ross,Pheobe and Rachel visits them often

Answer (score 7):

I didn't had the occasion to watch [Joey](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0375355/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), But if this show is canon, Joey (apparently) moved to Los Angeles.

So no matter what was meant to be. He did not live with Chandler (for at least two years we know about).